# PDO соединение только для чтения

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Возможноли с помощью PDO открыть соединение только для чтения? Тоесть любые mysql запросы на запись выдадут ошибку, а на чтение все ок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант эту проблему можно решить не на уровне PDO-драйвера, а на уровне прав доступа mysql-пользователя. Вы можете разрешить пользователю выполнение только SELECT-запросов к базе данных `dbname` при помощи оператора `GRANT TABLE` следующего вида

```
GRANT SELECT ON dbname.* TO 'read'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: Безопастнее как-то на уровне PDO.

Comment: Пользователя, не вариант, паралельно этим пользователем пользуются и другие люди, которым разрешена запись.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, не факт, одно приложение обезопасите, а другие нет - они могу обращаться к этой же самой базе вообще не через PDO и не через ваш слой приложения. Если действовать через readonly-пользователя, какой бы драйвер вы не применяли, сервер просто не даст выполнить приложение. А почему бы не завести несколько соединений на уровне приложения с разными пользователями? readonly, write... или это какая-то система прав доступа?

Comment: Это php:)  Хотя идея ваша про несколько пользователей интересна. Спасибо за наводку.